# Problems identifying with 'mysterious' calls to action index methods in controllers

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

I have an issue with calls to action methods being made before, during and after the 1st valid routing path is being processed by VS.

It's difficult for me to provide code because the issue is not related to any particular call I make to these action methods. If I put breakpoints on these known calls, they are never hit, only the actual action method is called.

I can give the routing I use though. If can see the thread in VS that calls these actions but how can I track what is creating these threads? It seems to want to try to load all controllers that match the routes but I thought it stops when it finds the 1st good route.

How can I stop VS from going beyond the unknown good route?

I'd be grateful for any hints at things I can check for.

I have searched for ways to show what calls action methods in controller but I'm not finding anything. Tried playing with `Request.UrlReferrer` but that always returns null.

What makes no sense is why the action index methods get called  including the return call to load a view but these views never get shown in the end.

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Root",
    url: "",
    defaults: new { controller = "Dashboard", action = "Index" }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Dashboard", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

No error msg.

Comment: Elaborate on "I have an issue with calls to action methods being made before, during and after the 1st valid routing path is being processed by VS" please, its hard to understand exactly what you are describing

Comment: VS actually goes through a number of controllers and loads a number of action methods to match the routes. This makes VS take forever to start when hitting F5.

Comment: Hi MKougiouris. Thanks. Index in Dashboard gets called but before the last statement in Dashboard's Index, VS goes aoff and cals those other actions.

Comment: Are you completely sure that there is no action been called when the index is loaded? Its not uncommon for actions to be called by accident if you have bound the onclick handlers wrongy and they run on html evalutation as well as when clicked, instead of only when clicked

Comment: I mean if there are a load of actions been called, probably you have bound your menu links wrongly maybe... and they just all fire when the browser evaluates the html

Comment: Hi. I'm pretty sure but thats why it would be good to visualise what is calling those actions.

Comment: will rename all calls to the controller VS calls and get back

Comment: Try Chrome dev tools. When you load the page you can see if it's making other requests. There could also be calls to controller methods from the view itself, like `@Html.Action("action", "controller", parameters)`

Comment: Renaming all ref's to the controller VS calls does nothing. It still goes to the index and loads it or any other 1st path it finds that matches the routes.